# How to handle file upload in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am displaying a html page using WKWebView in Swift 5. I have an option to upload image using input file tag. When I run the app and click on upload, it prompts to select Photo library or Camera. If I select camera, the app crashes since the app doesn't have permission.

How to remove camera option or properly request the permission when the user selects camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but you can just set key **Privacy - Camera Usage** Description in info.plist file with description. Web view will manage for permission and it will work. Please check and let me know if work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After setting the key, now I am able to use camera to upload photo. Is there anyway to disable the option of using camera?

Comment: https://addpipe.com/html-media-capture-demo/
https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/
https://github.com/addpipe/HTML-Media-Capture-Correct-Syntax

Here some reference URL for capture type of HTML input tag which control the import option I think. Please check and let me know if anyone work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question - "How to remove camera option":

As far as I know it is not possible. You can either show a dialog which asks for image source (library, camera or Files) or you can select camera only using `capture`:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

Something like `capture`, but for Photo Library is not supported.

Check filter options [here](https://addpipe.com/html-media-capture-demo/).